# mail() in php doesn't work?

Tags: php

**CODE:**

```
<h2>Feedback Form</h2>
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
// display form if user has not clicked submit
if (!isset($_POST["submit"]))
  {
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];?>">
  From: <input type="text" name="from"><br>
  Subject: <input type="text" name="subject"><br>
  Message: <textarea rows="10" cols="40" name="message"></textarea><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Feedback">
  </form>
  <?php 
  }
else
  // the user has submitted the form
  {
  // Check if the "from" input field is filled out
  if (isset($_POST["from"]))
    {
    $from = $_POST["from"]; // sender
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];
    // message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    // send mail
    mail("samy_zaki@ymail.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
    echo "Thank you for sending us feedback";
    }
  }
?>
```

**Error:**
Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.0\www\contact us.php on line 30
Thank you for sending us feedback

Comment: i know put it is not work !

Comment: You still have 127.0.0.1 in your error message, that clearly means you haven't tried it yet. Please update your error message so we can help you further

Comment: do you have Install or Properly configure an SMTP server on 127.0.0.1 port 25?

Comment: it is the mail function in php.ini what is my problem ?

[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = smtp.yahoo.com
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

Answer (score 0):

**Using php.ini**:

- Open `php.ini`
- Search for `SMTP` in the `php.ini`. In general, you'll find `SMTP=localhost`. change the `localhost` to the smtp server name of your ISP. And the set the port of 25.

  ```
  SMTP = aspmx.l.google.com # your smtp server address
  smtp_port = 25
  ```
- Restart the apache server
- Now try to send the mail using the `mail()` function

**Using ini_set:**

```
<?php
ini_set('SMTP',"aspmx.l.google.com"); // your smtp server address
ini_set('smtp_port',25);
?>
```

Source: [Sending email with PHP](http://www.myaakriti.com/web/php/sending-email-with-php/)

Comment: does not work ! :( i have the same problem

Comment: Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.ntc.net.np" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.0\www\contact us.php on line 30

Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.0\www\contact us.php on line 30

Comment: You need to replace smtp.ntc.net.np with your ISPs SMTP address

Comment: For example, `aspmx.l.google.com` this one should work for you too

Comment: Warning: mail(): SMTP server response: 550-5.1.1 The email account that you tried to reach does not exist. Please try in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.0\www\contact us.php on line 30
Thank you for sending us feedback

and i change the mail and it does not work